# Asignar funcion a nuevos botones en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy realizando una gui en tkinter la cual realiza un ping test a una IP "X" la gui tiene 2 botones que en caso de el ping ser verdadero se pone verde y en caso contrario rojo.

La problematica es que quiero agregar 2 botones mas y 1 entry, lo realize pero no logro que se realice los 2 ping en simultaneo.

les dejo el codigo.

```
import subprocess as sub
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class test (tk.Tk):
    def ping(self):
      try:
        self.withdraw()
        result=sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "1500", conf_ip.get()],shell=True).wait()
        if result == 0:
          # print ('Active')
          B = btn_ping
          B ['bg'] = 'green'
          B2 = btn_ping2
          B2 ['bg'] = 'white'
        else:
          # print ('Inactive')
          B2 = btn_ping2
          B2 ['bg'] = 'red'
          B = btn_ping
          B ['bg'] = 'white'
        self.after(1500, self.ping)
      except:
        quit()
        
        

    def __init__(self):
      tk.Tk.__init__(self)
      global conf_ip, ping_ip,btn_ping,btn_ping2, window
      window = tk.Tk()
      window.title("Ping Aplicacion")
      window.attributes('-topmost',True)
      window.geometry('375x300')
      window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

      lbl = Label(window, text='Ping 1')
      lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)

      ping_ip= StringVar()

      btn_ping= Button(window, text='Online')
      btn_ping.config(width=25, height=1)
      btn_ping.grid(row=4, column=1)
      
      btn_ping2= Button(window, text='Offline')
      btn_ping2.config(width=25, height=1)
      btn_ping2.grid(row=4, column=4)
      
      conf_ip = Entry(window, state='normal', textvariable=ping_ip)
      conf_ip.grid(row=6, column=1)
      conf_ip.insert(END, '127.0.0.1')
      ping_ip.set('IP')
      
      
      

app = test()
app.ping()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¿Quieres añadir los otros dos botones y el entry en la misma ventana, o en una distinta?

Comment: en la misma ventana

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he solucionado con un hilo. Por una parte tienes el hilo que se encarga de la funcionabilidad de la ventana, para que puedas modificar los valores del entry, y a su vez un hilo que vaya haciendo el método ping. Así me funciona:

```
import subprocess as sub
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading


class test(tk.Tk):
    def ping(self):
        try:
            #self.withdraw()
            result = sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "1500", conf_ip.get()], shell=True).wait()
            if result == 0:
                #print ('Active')
                B = btn_ping
                B['bg'] = 'green'
                B2 = btn_ping2
                B2['bg'] = 'white'
            else:
                #print ('Inactive')
                B2 = btn_ping2
                B2['bg'] = 'red'
                B = btn_ping
                B['bg'] = 'white'

            #self.withdraw()
            result = sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "1500", self.conf_ip_2.get()], shell=True).wait()
            if result == 0:
                #print ('Active 2')
                self.btn_ping_2['bg'] = 'green'
                self.btn_ping2_2['bg'] = 'white'
            else:
                #print ('Inactive 2')
                self.btn_ping2_2['bg'] = 'red'
                self.btn_ping_2['bg'] = 'white'

            # self.after(1500, self.ping())
        except:
            print('error')
            quit()
        self.update()
        print('dormir...\n\n\n')
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print('Realizando ping...')
        self.ping()

    def __init__(self):
        print('inicializamos')
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        global conf_ip, ping_ip, btn_ping, btn_ping2, window
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Ping Aplicacion")
        window.attributes('-topmost', True)
        window.geometry('375x300')
        window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

        lbl = Label(window, text='Ping 1')
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)

        ping_ip = StringVar()

        btn_ping = Button(window, text='Online')
        btn_ping.config(width=25, height=1)
        btn_ping.grid(row=4, column=1)

        btn_ping2 = Button(window, text='Offline')
        btn_ping2.config(width=25, height=1)
        btn_ping2.grid(row=4, column=4)

        conf_ip = Entry(window, state='normal', textvariable=ping_ip)
        conf_ip.grid(row=6, column=1)
        conf_ip.insert(END, '127.0.0.1')
        ping_ip.set('IP')

        ####

        lbl_2 = Label(window, text='Ping 2')
        lbl_2.grid(row=10, column=1)

        self.ping_ip_2 = StringVar()

        self.btn_ping_2 = Button(window, text='Online')
        self.btn_ping_2.config(width=25, height=1)
        self.btn_ping_2.grid(row=14, column=1)

        self.btn_ping2_2 = Button(window, text='Offline')
        self.btn_ping2_2.config(width=25, height=1)
        self.btn_ping2_2.grid(row=14, column=4)

        self.conf_ip_2 = Entry(window, state='normal', textvariable=self.ping_ip_2)
        self.conf_ip_2.grid(row=16, column=1)
        self.conf_ip_2.insert(END, '127.0.0.1')
        self.ping_ip_2.set('IP')



app = test()
t = threading.Thread(target=app.ping)
t.start()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo estoy probando pero al realizar un ping a una ip no valida el algoritmo se "cuelga" se demora...

Comment: ¿Cuánto se demora? Porque si son 5 segundos lo que tarda puede pasar, porque tarde más o lo que sea. Sino siempre puedes crear otro hilo solamente para el ping_2, así no te retrasaría la consulta del primer ping.

Comment: al agregar otro ping se relentiza, necesito ingresar 10 ip aproximadamente.

Comment: Con 10 ips, lo normal es que te vaya lento. Puedes hacer 4 hilos donde consultes 2 ips. Para que te vaya más rápido., quita el time.sleep(0.2) y modificar algunas cosas como cambiar el fondo de los botones así: `self.btn_ping_2['bg']= 'green' if resultado == 0 else 'white'`

Comment: Estoy viendo quue cuando esta en ejecucion se cuelga, sabes como puedo haver para que realiza el ping solo "10" veces por ejemplo para asi no colgar el programa?

Comment: Ya tengo la solución. Cuando modifiques el Entry, que se ejecute el método ping de ese Entry en concreto, y que cada x tiempo vuelva a ejecutarse si no se ha vuelto a modificar.